# Trying to redirect to url in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to redirect my app to a specific website when the app is opened through a custom url (foo://). Using this URL leads me to here in the AppDelegate.

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options:[String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let viewController = ViewController();
    viewController.loadRequestExt()
    return true
}
```

which calls the `loadRequestExt()` function in the ViewController

```
func loadRequestExt() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadView()
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    self.webView!.loadRequest(requestObj);
    self.loadView()
}

override func loadView() {
    print("loadView")
    super.loadView()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController();
    contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
        self,
        name: "iOS"
    )

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController

    self.webView = WKWebView(
        frame: self.view.frame,
        configuration: config
    )
    self.view = self.webView
    self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self

    // configure the activity view
    activityView.center = self.view.center
    activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityView.startAnimating()

    self.view.addSubview(activityView)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("viewDidLoad")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(registerPushToken), name: "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken", object: nil)

    let url = NSURL (string: "http://charlycares-frontend.herokuapp.com/#/app/login");

    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    self.webView!.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

It goes into the loadView and executes the `loadRequest`, however it stays on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your `viewcontroller` as `rootviewcontroller` of window property in `appdelegate` (I suppose that you are not using storyboard, in that case, you must set your `viewcontroller` as initial `viewcontroller` and don't add code to `appdelegate`):

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options:[String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()    

    return true
}
```

In your `ViewController` `viewDidLoad`, call your `loadRequest` function:

```
self.loadRequestExt()
```